# How to generate sef url in a custom joomla 4 module

Tags: joomla, joomla4

I have the following code in a custom module that displays the intro content of all articles in a category and below each of their content, it shows a link to that article.

It is working fine on the Joomla 3 site. I am migrating the site to Joomla 4 but the same code is producing non-sef links.

```
<?php
    $rootURL = rtrim(JURI::base(),'/');
    $subpathURL = JURI::base(true);
    if(!empty($subpathURL) && ($subpathURL != '/')) {
        $rootURL = substr($rootURL, 0, -1 * strlen($subpathURL));
    }
    $url =  JRoute::_(ContentHelperRoute::getArticleRoute($item->id,  $item->catid));           

?>
<a href="<?php echo $url; ?>">Link to this article</a>
```

On Joomla 3 site this is producing links in this format:

https://abcxyz.com/help/mobile-web-access/110-faq/licensing/134-desktop-web-mobile-license-details

But the same code is generating the following link on Joomla 4:

https://abcxyz.com/help/mobile-web-access?view=article&id=134&catid=110

This is happening with all the links that are generated by the above code snippet. As you can see the ids of the articles and categories are the same. The menus are also the same.

Any idea what might be the issue? What do I need to do to make it generate the links in the same format as before?

Comment: Please ask Joomla questions on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.